# Why is the imageView size stretched when scrolling in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I made a `UITableViewCell` with image label and button but when I scroll down the size of the imageview will increase and cover the label in all cells as in attached images..why is this issue happening and how can I resolve this it?
thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Make sure `UIImageView` `clipToBound` is true and what constraint set for `UIImageView`?

Comment: Please add the code of your `cellForRow` method. You might be doing something with the imageView's frame in there that cause the issue.

Comment: issue with constraints you added . check and add correctly

Comment: @Kuldeep i used clipToBound and still the same, i use autoconstraints for trailing, leading, top and bottom. and the leading label supposed start from the trailing of Imageview but in run time the image covers the label

Comment: @Vinodh I don't do anything in code for the views
implementation ImgTitleButtonCell
{
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
}
end

Comment: @BadhanGanesh i just set the cell views with values in this method
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ImgTitleButtonCell *cell;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    return cell;
}